# Select with limited join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `products` and `products_prices`.

`products` table:

| id | name | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Headphones | 1 |
| 2 | Phone | 1 |

`products_prices` table:

| id | product_id | price | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 15 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 20 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 10 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 15 | 5 |
| 6 | 2 | 20 | 6 |

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (user_id = 1) LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

So I need to get limited rows from `products` table with only two prices values from table `product_prices` ordered by `time` for each row in `products`.

(I need to get product with two latest prices).

This is example of what I want to get:

| id | user_id | name | curr_price | prev_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | Phone | 20 | 15 |

And example of my query:

```
select products.*,
       (SELECT price FROM products_prices WHERE product_id = products.id ORDER BY time asc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) as curr_price,
        (SELECT price FROM products_prices WHERE product_id = products.id ORDER BY time asc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) as prev_price
from "products"
    where (products."user_id" = 1)
limit 1 offset 1
```

Is it possible to do it **without subqueries**?

Comment: Maybe... depends on what you call subquery.  You can use lateral/cross apply to do this.  It will be an additional JOIN; but not a subquery.  it's not a where cluase or select sub query, but it is an inline view within the from clause itself executing a second select agasint the same table.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html 7.2.1.5. LATERAL Subqueries  so depends on definition I guess...  you could also assign a row number to each window and select where row number <=2... but that would be a subquery too...

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data (another user_id etc.), and also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: I suppose you might be able to use lead to get look ahead to the next record value within each window(product)... then you wouldn't get multiple rows in the result just 1 per product...  What's expected output look like?  2 columns with the price or do you need two rows of data?

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of the subqueries?

Comment: xQbert, for query optimisation purposes. I need to display 10-15 product items per request, so I guess 30 select operations will be not pretty good.

Comment: have you tried it?  multiple queries can mean multiple threads and run in parallel so performance may be fine.  Indexes, data volume, hardware, data partitions  all add to unknowns when evaluating "performance" you could try each look at the explain plan for each query and determine what's best for you.  There is no Silver bullet here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I find any of these easier to read...

0th approach using window functions and a CTE [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=82648bd15de3d09c958a36184811e56a)

```
With products as (SELECT 1 ID, 'Headphones' name, 1 user_id UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 ID, 'Phone' name, 1 user_id ),
products_Prices as (SELECT 1 ID, 1 Product_ID, 10 price, 1 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 1 Product_ID, 15 price, 2 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 ID, 1 Product_ID, 20 price, 3 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 ID, 2 Product_ID, 33 price, 4 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 ID, 2 Product_ID, 22 price, 5 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 6 ID, 2 Product_ID, 11 price, 6 time),
STEP1 as (
SELECT  P.ID, P.Name, P.user_ID,
  price as CurrentPrice, lead(price) over (partition by P.ID order by time desc) Prev_Price, time,
  row_number() over (Partition by P.ID order by time Desc) RN
FROM Products  P
LEFT JOIN  Products_Prices Z
  on Z.Product_ID = P.ID)
SELECT Id, Name, User_ID, CurrentPRice, PRev_Price
From Step1 where RN = 1
```

Giving us:

```
+----+------------+---------+--------------+------------+
| id |    name    | user_id | currentprice | prev_price |
+----+------------+---------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | Headphones |       1 |           20 |         15 |
|  2 | Phone      |       1 |           11 |         22 |
+----+------------+---------+--------------+------------+
```

1st  approach using analytics and a CTE:  note I changed price numbers to show variance.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f45978c0e75fee94c8cdf62437621547)

```
With products as (SELECT 1 ID, 'Headphones' name, 1 user_id UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 ID, 'Phone' name, 1 user_id ),
products_Prices as (SELECT 1 ID, 1 Product_ID, 10 price, 1 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 1 Product_ID, 15 price, 2 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 ID, 1 Product_ID, 20 price, 3 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 ID, 2 Product_ID, 33 price, 4 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 ID, 2 Product_ID, 22 price, 5 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 6 ID, 2 Product_ID, 11 price, 6 time),
STEP1 as (SELECT  P.ID, P.Name, P.user_ID, PP.price, row_number() over (partition by PP.product_ID order by time desc) RN
          FROM Products  P
          LEFT JOIN products_prices  PP
            on P.ID = PP.Product_ID)
SELECT ID, Name, User_ID, max(case when RN = 1 then Price end) as Current_price, max(case when RN=2 then price end) as Last_price
FROM STEP1 
WHERE RN <=2
GROUP BY ID, name, User_ID
```

Giving us:

```
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
| id |    name    | user_id | current_price | last_price |
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
|  2 | Phone      |       1 |            11 |         22 |
|  1 | Headphones |       1 |            20 |         15 |
+----+------------+---------+---------------+------------+
```

Option 2 using lateral.
[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a58ac7c98a7f03f6984c5d9356dd7765)

```
With products as (SELECT 1 ID, 'Headphones' name, 1 user_id UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 ID, 'Phone' name, 1 user_id ),
products_Prices as (SELECT 1 ID, 1 Product_ID, 10 price, 1 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 ID, 1 Product_ID, 15 price, 2 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 ID, 1 Product_ID, 20 price, 3 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 ID, 2 Product_ID, 33 price, 4 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5 ID, 2 Product_ID, 22 price, 5 time UNION ALL
                    SELECT 6 ID, 2 Product_ID, 11 price, 6 time)
SELECT  P.ID, P.Name, P.user_ID, PP.price, time
FROM Products  P
LEFT JOIN lateral (SELECT Product_ID, Price, time 
                   FROM Products_Prices Z
                   WHERE Z.Product_ID = P.ID
                   ORDER BY Time Desc LIMIT 2) PP
on TRUE
ORDER BY TIME DESC;
```

Givng us : (unpivoted) and using the row number logic above we could pivot.

```
+----+------------+---------+-------+------+
| id |    name    | user_id | price | time |
+----+------------+---------+-------+------+
|  2 | Phone      |       1 |    11 |    6 |
|  2 | Phone      |       1 |    22 |    5 |
|  1 | Headphones |       1 |    20 |    3 |
|  1 | Headphones |       1 |    15 |    2 |
+----+------------+---------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Is it good solution from point of query optimisation? I need to display 10-15 product items per page, so from your example how many queries will be executed?

Comment: too many unknowns we'd have to evaluate the execution plans of each to see what's best for your enviornment.  And as data changes the "Best" could change... or indexes could improve or partitions on data could be added...